# Angular Append Menu Items to Const

Tags: arrays, angular

The construct 'MENUITEMS' is required to be conditionally built based on bool values but when I try to push new values I get the error:

Type '{ state: string; name: string; type: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ state: string; name: string; type: string; icon: string; children: { state: string; name: string; type: string; }[]; }': icon, children ts(2739)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface ChildrenItems {
    state: string;
    name: string;
    type?: string;
}

export interface Menu {
    state: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    icon: string;
    requiredSubscriptions: [],
    children?: ChildrenItems[];
}


const MENUITEMS = [
    {
        state: 'vertical',
        name: 'Vertical Menu',
        type: 'button',
        icon: ''
    },
    {
        name: 'General',
        type: 'sub',
        class: 'group-title',
        icon: '',
        children: [
            {
                state: 'horizontal/dashboard',
                name: 'DASHBOARD',
                type: 'subChild',
                icon: 'explore',
                children: [
                    { state: 'mail', name: 'MAILROOM', type: 'link' },
                    { state: 'inventory', name: 'INVENTORY', type: 'link' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

if (this.isMailroomAdmin) {
    MENUITEMS.push(
        {
            state: 'horizontal/mail',
            name: 'MAILROOM',
            type: 'subChild',
            icon: 'envelope',
            label: 'New',
            children: [
                { state: 'addmail', name: 'Add Mail', type: 'link' },
                { state: 'removemail', name: 'Remove Mail', type: 'link' }
            ]
        }
    )
}

if (this.isInventoryAdmin) {
    MENUITEMS.push(
        {
            state: 'horizontal/inventory',
            name: 'INVENTORY',
            type: 'subChild',
            icon: 'carton',
            label: 'New',
            children: [
                { state: 'addinventory', name: 'Add Inventory', type: 'link' },
                { state: 'removeinventory', name: 'Remove Inventory', type: 'link' }
            ]
        }
    )
}

@Injectable()
export class HorizontalMenuItems {
    getAll() {
        return MENUITEMS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first mark MENUITEMS as Menu:

```
const MENUITEMS: Menu[] = [...]
```

The other problem is this item, because its children array doesn't have the same structure (it seems to be an array of Menu not of ChildrenItems):

```
    {
        name: 'General',
        type: 'sub',
        class: 'group-title',
        icon: '',
        children: [
            {
                state: 'horizontal/dashboard',
                name: 'DASHBOARD',
                type: 'subChild',
                icon: 'explore',
                children: [
                    { state: 'mail', name: 'MAILROOM', type: 'link' },
                    { state: 'inventory', name: 'INVENTORY', type: 'link' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the third problem is that you have a property `requiredSubscriptions` which is not marked as optional (with `?`) but it's not visible anywhere in your MENUITEMS. Either mark it optional or add it to each item inside MENUITEMS.